# PHP auto_prepend_file MySQL error logger

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fastcgi

I need some help identifying the issue with what I'm trying to do so thanks in advance for any help you can provide. I'm trying to use php ***auto_prepend_file*** to set ***set_error_handler*** and ***register_shutdown_function*** to run a function that will catch any errors and log them to a MySql Database. I got this partly working but it has some unexplained behavior and I can't seem to understand why, maybe a PHP bug I'm not sure?

**Behaviors**

**1.)** When I place the logger code outside of the ***auto_prepend_file*** lets say in my index.php that I request I get the full error written to the database, but when I place the code inside the auto_prepend_file that is loaded I get a partly cut version of the error as you can see the **Undefined index: page** error in the screen shot below.

**2.)** When I place the ***register_shutdown_function*** inside the auto_prepend_file it doesn't work if triggered by a fatal error, but when I place it outside in the index.php that I request it will work.

[image: Screenshot of logged errors]

**Setup Information**

```
OS: Windows
Server: IIS
PHP: 7.1.9
```

**.user.ini**

```
auto_prepend_file = "C:\IIS\Sites\site\log.php"
```

**log.php**

```
function myErrorHandlerr($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $error_context) {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "log";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // prepare and bind
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO error_logs (error) VALUES (?)");

        $errorssssss = $errstr.$errfile. $errline.$errno . $error_context;
        // var_dump($errorssssss);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $errorssssss);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
}

function shutdownHandler()
{
    $lasterror = error_get_last();
    switch ($lasterror['type'])
    {
        case E_ERROR:
        case E_CORE_ERROR:
        case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
        case E_USER_ERROR:
        case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
        case E_CORE_WARNING:
        case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
        case E_PARSE:
            $error = "[SHUTDOWN] lvl:" . $lasterror['type'] . " | msg:" .$lasterror['message'] . " | file:" . $lasterror['file'] . " | ln:" . $lasterror['line'];
        myErrorHandlerr($error, "fatal",'','','');
    }
}

set_error_handler("myErrorHandlerr", E_ALL | E_STRICT);
register_shutdown_function("shutdownHandler");
```

Comment: Okay I understand where your coming from but is a little off topic..correct me if I'm wrong but this shouldn't be and issue as long as we maintain our code and make sure we are fixing and issues that might cause errors/warnings to be logged to the php log file. The DB connection would only happen on a php error/warning and I want those errors/warnings logged in to a central database since I have multiple servers to manage. I plan on implementing this in dev and test so it really shouldn't hinder performance anyways.

Comment: You should be using a proper connection pool to avoid this mess. Using `register_shutdown_function` is also pretty heavy-handed, there's many opportunities to catch exceptions before they become fatal. I'm not sure what the goal is here. There's a very high probability that the reason your app is crashing is because the database is down, so database-driven logging is problematic.

Comment: I understand there are many ways to catch exceptions before they become fatal and I understand your approach to this question but that's where mixed up. The goal here is to make the code above work. I want to catch all errors for the servers in a central database so they can be reviewed and fixed. I use open source software such and wordpress that uses plugins written by 3rd parties. Not all the plugins are written correctly as you and I would hope they would do so I have little to no control when it comes to the maintainability of the code base. The code doesn't appear to be crashing ?